# MySQL error: Can't get hostname from your ip address

Tags: mysql, ip, hostname

I use my remote MySQL database during long time.

But today I suddenly have found that I cannot connect to the database. I have got an error.

> "Can't get hostname from your ip address".

I haven't changed anything in MySQL settings.

What's the problem?

Comment: tried `ping yourMySQLHostIP` ?

Comment: I have restarted the MySQL service on the remote server but it did not help.

Comment: I have a site on the same server. It works fine if I type the IP of the server into the browser address bar.

Comment: As the error states : MySQL is unable to resolve your current IP to a hostname (ie. it cannot perform a reverse lookup on your current IP). Check [this bug report](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=52923) and also [how MySQL uses DNS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/dns.html) for some background info.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Just add below in `my.ini` or `my.cnf`.

```
[mysqld]

skip-name-resolve
```

**Linux:**

Otherwise, start MySQL server with the following flag:

```
sudo service --skip-name-resolve
```

For more information: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/host-cache.html

Comment: i am having same problem. Can anyone explain how to resolve it. This answer is not clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question was asked quite some time ago and most people have figured it out by now, but for those who haven't, here was my solution:

Add the port number with the server name in you connection string

```
connectionstring = "server=server;Port=3306;User Id=UserNAme;password=password;Persist Security Info=True;database=DatabaseName;convert zero datetime=true";
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same error message on windows. I found my problem is the local server host file. Check the localhost or any hostname you use in the file c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\host

My original host file:
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1         localhost

I just delete the second line and use the first line only:
127.0.0.1   localhost

Then, problem solved, for my problem. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem when installing MySQL 8 on a Windows 10 machine. Most of the solutions found on the internet are setting `skip-name-resolve` which never worked for me. At last I found out this one which worked for me:

`netsh winsock reset`

Then reboot the computer. Also try set

`127.0.0.1 localhost`

in `%windir%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` if needed.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, is by changing the name of the computer (`B2` to `BBB`) which changes the numeric value from the Hostname of computer.