# MySQL check incoming hostname (Linux)

Tags: mysql, linux

I have a user that needs access to the database. I set him up a user but he is telling me what his host name is and I added that host name for the username, but he cannot connect. I think there may be some disconnect and was hoping there may be a way to see which hostname is coming thru. He is connecting to our network via VPN so I think something may be changing with the host name. Thanks

Comment: The MySQL error message should include the hostname from where to connection is not allowed. Use that hostname in the privilege. (In case of VPN connection that must be one your internal hostnames.)

Comment: Oh, this is what the mysql client returned in error, "MySQL said: Can't get hostname for your address"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In light of "MySQL said: Can't get hostname for your address" in your comment, this must be related to VPN configuration then. You or your network admin should be able to tell what is your box's hostname on the private network and that should be used as host in the MySQL user table.

Turning off name resolving for the MySQL server might also help: [MySQL error: Can't get hostname from your ip address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5118151/mysql-error-cant-get-hostname-from-your-ip-address)

Answer (score 0):

MySQL's permission system grants permissions per user@host. Meaning joe@localhost for example may have different permissions than joe@some-host.

Example:

```
// grants all permissions to joe if he connects from localhost
CREATE USER 'joe'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'secret';
GRANT ALL ON db1.* TO 'joe'@'localhost';

// grants select permissions to joe if he connects from "other-host"
CREATE USER 'joe'@'other-host' IDENTIFIED BY 'secret';
GRANT SELECT ON db1.* TO 'joe'@'other-host';
```

If you don't care about the host at all you can use `joe@*`.

Further reading: [Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html#grant-privileges)

Comment: I already did that but like I said, it wont let him connect and when I run hostname on his computer, what it is showing is what I added but yet it wont let him connect. So either I have a problem with his hostname or something else is broken

Comment: Did you executed `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` after that? What does `nslookup HOSTNAME` gives you (when executed from the mysql server's shell?) If you have no name resolution in your network, you need to use (static) IP's as hostname.