# Can't get hostname from your ip address

Tags: mysql

This is a Duplicate to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5118151/mysql-error-cant-get-hostname-from-your-ip-address) question. But the given answer did not solved my problem. I have mysql installed which is accessed from other computers in the network with my ipaddress/phpmyadmin.

I also added line `skip_name_resolve=1` to my my.ini file but this also din't worked. I cannot even take backup now.

I installed mysql on another pc and copied the databases from xampp/mysql/data from previous mysql folder. But the database does not has all the tables. **Plz suggest something to resolve the problem or if there is any way i can take backup.**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting is a problem with resolving the hostname given for the MySQL connection string. Check your DNS entry for the host in question, modify your /etc/hosts to statically point to it, etc

Also this isn't a question of programming, rather of system, so...

Comment: you rightly pointed out it isn't a programming question. I can't even access mysql from my pc. Can you tell how to check my DNS entry and how to modify /etc/hosts. It would of great help.

Comment: The problem isn't with your MySQL, it is with phpMyAdmin, do you know where it points? i.e. which host it points to?

Comment: I tried to access mysql using cmd prompt but it also gives same error. XAMPP is installed on my pc and i access it with localhost/phpmyadmin. I don't know where should it point.

Comment: Your question is outside the scope of this, I suggest you try Super User or XAMPP support page